# Decorated function return multiple value

Tags: python

I have the following decorator:

```
def my_deco(limit=None):
    def wrap_outer(func):
        def wrap_inner(*args, **kwargs):
                return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrap_inner
    return wrap_outer
```

It call the actual decorated function by

```
func(*args, **kwargs)
```

If a function return multiple values, this will return a **single tuple that contains 3, and 4**. How do I keep the multiple value returning behavior, instead of a tuple?

```
@my_deco()
def f(): 
    return 3, 4
```

Comment: A tuple is what multiple return values *are*.

Comment: They're the same thing. `return 3, 4` returns the tuple `(3, 4`).

Comment: Incidentally: in any recent-ish version of Python, you can do deconstructive assignment on functions returning a tuple: `a, b = function_returning_a_tuple()` will assign the individual tuple values to `a` and `b` assuming it's a 2-tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the mechanism that Python uses to return multiple values is to return a tuple.

This is pretty easy to see in a stripped down example:

```
def f():
  return 3, 4

print(type(f()))

<class 'tuple'>
```

And, it should also be noted that this isn't something that happens behind the scenes through some magic; `3, 4` alone creates a tuple before the function even returns.

So to answer your question, this is a non-problem. The behavior is the same in both cases.